# replace sequence of bytes in file

Tags: python, file, replace

What's the most efficient / pythonic way of replacing multiple occurrences of a sequence of 3 bytes in a file?

I started by loading the whole file into memory, searching, replacing, lather, rinse, repeat. But as I was pointed out by the 'homework reviewers' my solution is inefficient as my file may be multiple terabytes, which would be challenging to put into memory. My alternative approach is to read byte-by-byte and approach it by comparing byte by byte, which sounds inefficient.

EDIT: edited for clarity. Hopefully.

Comment: Rephrase the question. Are you only trying to replace 3 bytes in the entire file? Or 3 bytes per line? Example data might help

Comment: Updated. I hope it's clearer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('workfile', 'r+b')
f.seek(5)      # Go to the 6th byte in the file
f.write('abc')
f.close()
```

I am assuming you need to replace at a known offset in the file; that's the only conclusion I can come up with from the poorly specified question.  If you mean replacing like 'a' becomes 'b' and 'c' becomes 'd', you should just read the file in small chunks, perform substitutions in them and write the result out.